# A certain integral domain has 17 elements. How many units does it have?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A certain integral domain has 17 elements. How many units does it have?

Comment: Is 17 prime? So...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$16$. Every non zero element is a unit. For if $a \in D$ consider $\{ab| b \in D, b\neq 0\}$ all the elements of this set are distinct and non zero since $D$ is an integral domain.
Thus there is a $b$ such that $ab=1$ and $a$ is a unit.

Comment: How does an integral domain imply that all the elements of the set are distinct?

Comment: @IlikeSerena multiplication by nonzero elements in a domain produces an injective map from the ring to itself. So, there are as many ab's as there are a's.

Comment: @rschwieb: Why would the map be injective?

Comment: @IlikeSerena because ab=cb implies a=c, in a domain. This follows from (a-c)b=0.

Comment: @rschwieb: Ah. I get it know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All finite integral domains are fields, hence there are 16 elements which are units, by the definition of a field.

Proof of the main claim:

Let $D$ be a finite integral domain and let $0\ne a\in D$. Then the set $$\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ is finite. Say $a^m=a^k$ for some $m<k$, then $$(a^{k-m}-1)a^m=0$$
Since $D$ is an integral domain and $a\ne 0$, it must be that $$a^{k-m}=1$$ hence $a^{k-m-1}$ is an inverse for $a$.